# How can I specify for SQL to read a string in ordinary quote in DuckDB?

Tags: python, sql, insert, quotes, duckdb

**I have written a python queries with DuckDB:**

```
import duckdb
con = duckdb.connect()
con.query('CREATE TABLE people(id INTEGER, name VARCHAR);')
con.query('INSERT INTO people VALUES (1, 'Mark'), (2, 'Hannes')')
```

**But receive an error message:**

`con.query('INSERT INTO people VALUES (1, 'Mark'), (2, 'Hannes')') ^ SyntaxError: invalid syntax. Perhaps you forgot a comma?`

As I understand the problem is with ordinary quote, which DB don`t see. How can I solve this problem?

I`m expecting to make insert query.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Python has two different quotes you can use for strings - single (') and double (")

So you can write code like this:

```py
con.query("INSERT INTO people VALUES (1, 'Mark'), (2, 'Hannes')")
```

or escape the internal quotes, like this:

```py
con.query('INSERT INTO people VALUES (1, \'Mark\'), (2, \'Hannes\')')
```

Comment: Thank you for answer, it worked for me!)